# SELECT min and max value from a part of a table in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, max, min

If I want to select min and max values from a whole table I can use this:

```
SELECT min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price FROM `prices`
```

But how to select min and max values from just a part of a table?
For example, I have 30 rows in a table. I want to select min and max values from first ten rows, then from second ten rows and then form the last 10.

I've tried something like

```
SELECT min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price FROM `prices` LIMIT 0,10
```

but this did not work.

How can I solve this problem with minimum queries?

Comment: Define "first ten rows".  What field are you using to determine the row order?

Comment: check my answer for getting arbitrary range of rows

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(PRICE) AS MinPrice, MAX(PRICE) AS MaxPrice FROM (SELECT PRICE FROM PRICES LIMIT 10) tmp;
```

moreover, MySQL have a cool feature that will let you return an arbitrary range of rows (eg return rows 10-20). This is very handy for displaying pages of records:

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

The above query will return rows 20-30.

So in short, to return rows from 20 to 30 in case of your query, you use:

```
SELECT MIN(PRICE) AS MinPrice, MAX(PRICE) AS MaxPrice 
FROM (SELECT PRICE FROM PRICES LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20);
```

YOU need to change the offset value to specify the start point of your range.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need. The final query was SELECT min(t1.price) as min_price, max(t1.price) as max_price FROM (SELECT price FROM `ko_base_kk_old` ORDER BY price LIMIT 0,10) as t1

Comment: I have updated it more for your understanding. and you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried :

```
SELECT min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price FROM 
    (SELECT price FROM `prices` LIMIT 0,10);
```

Comment: oops i had the same answer :)

Comment: @reggie : It's true. You could even use an `order by` in the 2nd `SELECT`. He just need to know that he can **fetch** any list of `price` in the 2nd and taking only the `min` and `max` thanks to the 1st select. Seems pretty logical. Anyway, since the OP didn't answer @JNK you can't know if `OFFSET` is required here.