# Selecting maximum value with offset > 0 returns nil

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to use `fresh_when last_modified: @conversations.maximum(:updated_at)` with pagination. However, when `@conversations` is on page 2, `updated_at` is being returned as `nil` even though there is one record in the set.

```
irb(mail):001:0> conversations = conversations.paginate(page: 1)
=> [10 conversations]

irb(main):002:0> conversations.maximum(:updated_at)
   (3.0ms)  SELECT MAX(`inbox_conversations`.`updated_at`) AS max_id FROM `inbox_conversations` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
=> 2013-01-09 05:12:10 UTC # Correct

irb(main):003:0> conversations = conversations.paginate(page: 2)
=> [10 conversations]

irb(main):004:0> conversations.maximum(:updated_at)
   (2.7ms)  SELECT MAX(`inbox_conversations`.`updated_at`) AS max_id FROM `inbox_conversations` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
=> nil # Not correct
```

Comment: left join is needed i tnk

Comment: No difference between left and inner join here.

Comment: You are extracting result from 11-20 is there any data at that pos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is misinterpreting what you want

```
SELECT MAX(`inbox_conversations`.`updated_at`) AS max_id FROM `inbox_conversations` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Means run the query and then take the first 10 results from offset 10. This returns nil because the result set has a single row - the maximum updated_at. What you wanted instead was the offset limit to affect the rows over which the maximum was calculated.

You could do this with a subquery, but I'd just do this calculation in ruby since you're loading the rows anyway, using the regular `Enunerable` methods. Something like

```
conversations.map(&:updated_at).max
```

Comment: In this case I don't have to load the rows anyways. With the `fresh_when` being the one and only query, I would never have to load the rest of the rows. What about using `ORDER BY updated desc` with an `OFFSET` and `LIMIT 1`. This would achieve the same result and be faster than getting all ten, no?

Comment: Well you only don't need to load the rows if the etag is actually fresh. But yes in that case that would probably be faster

Answer (score 1):

SQL MAX query does not work with OFFSET ([plain SQL workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957786/select-min-and-max-value-from-a-part-of-a-table-in-mysql))

Any ActiveRecord `.offset(n).maximum(:field)` gives nil if `n > 0`

Try to use plain Ruby as a workaround (it saves you an query in advance).

```
conversations.max_by(&:updated_at)
```